# Sticky Footer with page scroll in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I try to make a responsive website which looks similar in Chrome, IE(11), and FF.

My problem in IE is, that if the site is too long the scrollbar doesn't scroll to the end because of the sticky page-footer('page-footer'). I tried to give my page-main-area a margin or padding bottom but that doesn't change anything.

Another thing is that my sidebar background doesn't fill to the end.

CSS extract:

```
.page-sidebar {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #00BB9C;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 58px;
}
.page-sidebar h3 {
    color: black;
}
.page-sidebar h3:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.page {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.page-main-area {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

}

.page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

HTML + CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/mvz8rq1o/2/

What can i do to fix this in IE?

Answer (score 0):

`margin-bottom:` on `page-sidebar` should get the full sidebar showing. (won't fix the fill-to-bottom however...)